# Spring Integration enriching payload using DSL

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to consume RSS feeds. Once I get a feed item, I need to enhance the data by using a field from the payload, call a Java class to get some additional data and store this with the payload before writing all the data to the DB.

What is the best way to do this, a payload enricher or a service activator and how to specify this using DSL?

Finally as the payload is an SyndEntry object, do I need to create a new payload with new fields?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a new payload type; you can use a simple POJO...

```
@Bean
public Enricher enricher() {
    return new Enricher();
}

public static class Enricher {

    public Enhanced enhance(SyndEntry entry) {
        return new Enhanced(entry, "foo", "bar");
    }

}
```

Then, in the DSL...

```
...
.handle("enricher", "enhance")
...
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. Very helpful.

Comment: Hi Gary, got this working. Just wanted to check something the code I need to run for enhancing the payload might take some time to execute (as it's making outbound API connections). If I put this code into the enhance method, this will need to complete before processing the next news item. Is there any way I can perform the payload enhancing in parallel for news items?

Comment: Add `.channel(Channels.executor(someTaskExecutorBean()))` before the `.handle()` and anything downstream will run on a thread supplied by the `TaskExecutor`.

Comment: Cheers Gary. I tried to use `Channels.executor` but it complained about a non-static method couldn't be referenced. I used `MessageChannels.executor` instead and now I can see the different threads being started.

Comment: Sorry, my bad doing it from memory.

Comment: what is the difference between .handle("enricher", "enhance") and .handle(enricher) ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it is hard for people to find questions/answers. The first is beanName/methodName (explicit method); the second is a bean instance, which must only have one method that is a match for the incoming payload.

Comment: ok. it is not a new question. I only thought - handle(enricher) was enough

Comment: You keep saying that. But it is a discrete question that would help others if asked at the top level instead of in a comment.

Comment: `handle(enricher)` **is** enough, as long as there is an unambiguous candidate method. I prefer to be explicit.